# is class instance inside static method thread safe

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety

I have a static method like follows

```
 public static void foo(){
     final ClassA a = new ClassA();
 }
```

I have two hash maps inside classA.

Are those hash map thread safe...?

Comment: it's unclear how those maps are used and defined. HashMap is not thread safe. But see concurrent hash maps: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear whether you mean to access the hash maps inside the object `a` with multiple threads or call the method `foo` with multiple threads.

In the first case thread safety of a collection has nothing to do with the outer context i.e. it was created in a static context or not. So no, if you try to access the hash maps from the object `a` with multiple threads, it will cause unexpected behavior. You need to regulate access to them with `synchronized` blocks.

In the second case, each thread will have a different copy of foo on its stack and allocate different instance of `ClassA`. Therefore, they will not collide because they will have different `HashMaps` to work with.

Please clarify which of there cases you are working with.

Answer (score 3):

if `HashMaps` inside `classA` are non static(created new for every new `ClassA()`), then you can call foo from multiple threads and be guaranteed that only one thread will ever run through the `HashMaps` inside the instance of `classA` created for that thread.

Answer (score 1):

I disagree (what am I missing)?

A new instance of ClassA is created inside the method.  Even if multiple threads access the method, each will have a unique HashMap to work with.

If ClassA was an instance variable, it would be different.  Also, if ClassA access the maps concurrently, threading issues will arise.

Also, if the maps are static multiple instances of ClassA would have access to it, and yes, that would be probamatic.

Answer (score 0):

The class `HashMap` is not thread-safe.

> Note that this implementation is not synchronized. If multiple threads access this map concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the map structurally, it must be synchronized externally

However when you call the code `foo` you will get a new `ClassA` each time, so two different threads that call `foo` will have access to different instances of `ClassA`. Assuming the hashmaps inside `ClassA` are not static or shared, the code should work correctly.

Comment: But is the new operation atomic?

Comment: If you're worried about threadsafe maps you can use Collections.synchronizedMap or ConcurrentHashMap

Comment: @chance, yes there is a system-wide lock that ensures two threads can't allocate heap memory at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are writing your code will make your static method available to all threads and hence each thread will get its own object of your class. So each class will be having its own hash maps.

But if you want to have same hash map for all threads then try making it `synchronized`.

Answer (score 0):

`HashMap` is not thread-safe, but assuming you never publish instance `a` nor its two hash maps outside `foo()`, then all three are confined to one thread and need not be thread-safe.

If you do publish `a` or its hash maps or if the hash maps are static members of `ClassA`, you should ensure thread safety. Assuming there are no invariants involving both hash maps or some other state variables you can simply use [`ConcurrentHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) to accomplish this. If there are such invariants you should synchronize, ideally as close to the state variables as possible, that is in `ClassA` rather than in `foo()`.